# Field Isomorphisms between a field and something that contains it

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Are there any k-isomorphism of fields between M and L such that K $\subseteq$ M $\subset$ L?
Examples would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How could there be if you set $M\subset L$?

Comment: @gitgud not good enough reasoning. For example, even if $X\subset Y$ properly, there can by a set isomorphism $X\cong Y$. While the fact we want a $k$-algebra isomorphism of fields and not just a bare isomorphism is more restrictive, we can in fact leverage the first example to get positive answers (as in Rene's below).

Comment: @blue Of course. I've been studying coding theory, so finite fields are all I see -_- Nevermind.

Answer (score 3):

Yes chose $L$ and $M$ to be two fields with the same infinite transcendence degree.

Comment: (and $M$ strictly contained in $L$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why haven't I thought about it before?